# What is my vocal type? Help me :D!

Tags: learning

Hi i am a young guy of an age 16 years! 
Now i'm wondering cause i'm confused with what vocal type i am! I have been testing myself at several music teachers and i have expanded through the years.
My vocal range is about.. A1 - G4 with a falsetto going from F#3 - G5 and a Tessitura of F3 - B5. And i can take a few whistle tones but i have never tried the vocal placement of those. They are at least pretty high. And this range should be pretty accurate since i wrote it down when i tested.

Thanks youu!

Comment: Whatever your vocal range is right now, in a year or two it will have settled, and possibly not be the same. Knowing your range is far more important than putting a label on it. So calm down, and maybe in 10 yrs time it will have re-developed - mine has- just enjoy singing! Tessitura, by the way, is applicable to pieces not one's range.

Answer (score 0):

So A1 as your lowest note.  That's quite lower than most basses can reach (typical bass ranges start a fifth higher).  And G5.  That's mezzosoprano range.  And your "tessitura", your useful range, is larger than that, reaching to B5, not a required note for choir sopranos any more.

So your vocal type is everything.  But since you are 16, it will likely change anyway.  It is pointless to first determine one's vocal type and then start training, like it is pointless to first determine one's best running distance and then start training.

First you develop your voice, then you specialize based on what you have available.  That may mean having to relearn some pieces in a different voice.  When I transitioned, there were concerts where I was switching around between bass, tenor, and alto, based on the general period the music was from and just when they had become part of my repertoire in that choir (I had begun as tenor but specialized on falsetto eventually, so I sang alto unless the period was wrong and I did bass in order not to strain my voice).

There really is no point in making decisions now and in particular in trying to stick to decisions when the voice develops differently.